# CodeIgniter 3.0 gives 404 on space in URL

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-3

If I have a URL like this:

`http://localhost/Cool Website/`

I will get this error:

`404 Page Not Found: The page you requested was not found: Cool Website/index`

However, when I use underscores like `http://localhost/Cool_Website/`

CodeIgniter loads as intended. This issue is now manifesting itself after pasting the CodeIgniter folder as a subfolder into our main project which has spaces in its name that I cannot change. (I can and have changed the CodeIgniter project's name to use underscores)

Is there a workaround for this?

**Update:** solved my issue by changing system files. I am running php 5.3.13.

I went to the URI core file and put this in the _parse_request_uri:

```
$uri = str_replace('%20', ' ', $uri);
```

At line 206, after `$uri = isset($uri['path']) ? $uri['path'] : '';`

This seems to have fixed it. I reverted the change to QUERY_STRING in my config file because QUERY_STRING was empty. This may be a CodeIgniter 3.0 bug. My guess is the 20% wasn't being "considered valid" by the uri code, so changing it back to a real space made it work again as it truly is the proper URL.

Comment: I would have a - or _ instead of a space folder name cool_website `http://localhost/cool_website`

Comment: Hey, there was another comment here that helped but it was deleted? It was not my base_url, but actually you can avoid this problem by going to your config and setting $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'; Unfortunately it seems my AJAX URLs aren't working... investigating now.

Comment: spaces are no matter with URL. Just try without any modification of code(remove `$uri = str_replace('%20', ' ', $uri);`).

Comment: You realize the only reason I put the code in is because spaces were not working? I wrote the code myself. I'm sure it's not a proper patch, but it worked for me. I will submit a bug report to CI when I can.